# Searching for a codes in a mysql database

Tags: mysql

I have a database that stores a large number of codes, these codes are used to validate submission of a form. When ever i run the following query i get zero rows back

```
SELECT * FROM `codes` WHERE `voucher` = 'JTBLYNQ9HA'
```

but when i run the following query it bring back the single row with the code in it.

```
SELECT * FROM  `codes` WHERE  `voucher` LIKE CONVERT( _utf8 '%JTBLYNQ9HA%' USING latin1 ) COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci LIMIT 0 , 30
```

What am i doing wrong which causes the first query to fail or should is it best practise to use the second query?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two queries are not equivalent. The first one is looking for a code whose voucher is exactly "JTBLYNQ9HA", the second one is looking for a code whose voucher contains that string (for instance, "ABCDEFGJTBLYNQ9HAHIJKLM").

The character set conversion and `COLLATE` are almost certainly irrelevant.

Comment: I dont understand why the first one would fail seeing as the code is exactly like that in the table. I will stick to the second one and remove the conversion and collate.Thanks